# how to access table or variable from php controller in angular js controller

Tags: php, html, angularjs, codeigniter, angular-ui-router

I am working in codeignitor.I want to to return table from php controller and want to access it in angular js controller.
Here is code for php controller.
Table.php

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Table extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

        $this->load->view('home');


        }
        public function live()
        {
$data=" .<table><tbody><tr> <th> a  </th><th>    b</th><th> c  </th>."
".</tr><tr<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr> </tbody></table> .";
or 
$data="one";

        return $data;
        }

}
```

Here is the code for route.js which has controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home',{
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
//            controller: 'mainctrl'
        })
        .state('live',{

            url:'/live',
            templateUrl: 'partials/show.html',
            controller: 'livectrl'
        })
});
   myApp.controller('livectrl',function($scope,$http,$location,$state){

        $http.get('/live').success(function(res){
         $scope.items=res;
        console.log($scope.items);
        console.log("work");
         $state.go('live');    
        }).
        error(function(err){

            alert(13);
        })

        });
```

Here is code for home.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>libs/js/route.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="livectrl">
 <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am listing the application at "localhost/tcric" when livectrl is called It returns the error in alert "13".
How can i Return data from php controller and access it in angular js controller.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make table data from php . best way in ajax call you return array of table row then in the angular application use ng-repeat to generate this table row .